# How to set Environment Variables on Flask/MongoDB on AWS ECS?

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, flask, amazon-ecs

I have a flask application that runs with MongoDB.

Locally, When I build and run the container using the following below, the app runs perfectly good locally.

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

These are the created containers:

```
/application$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                           NAMES
9e054b28bb46        application_web     "/bin/sh -c 'python …"   38 seconds ago      Up 37 seconds       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 27017/tcp   application_web_1
2a19a8e9a267        mongo:3.0.2         "/entrypoint.sh mong…"   39 seconds ago      Up 38 seconds       0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp        application_db_1
```

I have the following in my **app.py**:

```
MONGODB_HOST = os.environ['DB_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR']
MONGODB_PORT = 27017

app = Flask(__name__)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
client = MongoClient(MONGODB_HOST, MONGODB_PORT)
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
web:
  build: .
  command: python -u app.py
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - .:/project
  environment:
    MONGODB_HOST: db
  links:
      - db

db:
  image: mongo:3.4
  command: mongod
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.6.1-alpine

MAINTAINER mebarkiakhalil@gmail.com

WORKDIR /project

ADD . /project

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 80

EXPOSE 27017

CMD ["mongod"]

ENV NAME Cheppers_DevOps_Challenge

ENTRYPOINT python app.py
```

The problem that I am facing, after pushing the images into AWS ECS then I create the cluster with given pushed repository for the container image, I always get this error in the task definition logs:

```
2019-10-08 14:19:02
MONGODB_HOST = os.environ['DB_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR']
KeyError: 'DB_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR'
```

Comment: You already have  `environment: MONGODB_HOST: db` defined. Add `DB_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR` there.

Comment: @AlexBlex you mean instead of `db` in `docker-compose.yml` I put `DB_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR` ?

Comment: no, please read https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: @LinPy locally it works like that. I don't know how, but on AWS it went wrong.

Comment: @LinPy but the problem is on AWS it does not work. I don't get what you mean here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to change mongo host :

```
MONGODB_HOST = "db"
```

this `os.environ['DB_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR']` will use the IP address of the container which you do not need since `compose` will handle that for you using the service names.

I think `AWS` handle the IP address in different way that is not a `dict` anymore ("KeyError")

Comment: It worked! The flask app is deployed and working on AWS! However, the MongoDB connection is not made  this is the error I got `pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: db:27017: [Errno -2] Name does not resolve`

Comment: I think in aws you can configure links : `"links": ["name:internalName", ...]` see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_network

Comment: I think I have added linking thing in `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: try to set them in aws

Comment: Does it mean I have to create another container within the cluster for MongoDB? (https://node.university/blog/10067/aws-ecs-containers)

Answer (score 1):

> pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: db:27017: [Errno -2] Name
>   does not resolve –

The reason is container does not link properly, If you are really interested to use linking in ECS, you should define both containers in the **same task definition** mean two container per one task definition, you **can not link container** from two different tasks definition.

Then you can refer the mongo container by the container as mentioned by @linpy.

So your  task definition for containers will look like this

[image]

and update linking section in task definition for python container or use JSON as mentioned in the comment.

[image]

> Does it mean I have to create another container within the cluster for
>   MongoDB?

If you create

- New DB task definition
- Service for DB

Then in the above case linking will not work, then you have to use [service discovery](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ecs-service-discovery/) or internal LB.

Comment: Thanks! I have couple of questions. While creating new task definition, which launch compatibility type should be use **Fargate** or **EC2**? Also, while creating the container for MongoDB, which image must be used? In your answer, it seems I give same image. What about the port mapping? Should it be `80`for Python container and `27017` for `db` container?

Comment: **Fargate** does not support linking. while in linking you do not need necessarily to publish port for internal communication, if you want to connect from external then publish the mongo port that is `27017`. you can use offical image